# How can i run a load for 10 minutes with 500 transactions/sec with 25 concurrent users ? Is this a valid scenario to achieve in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I have tried with concurrent users thread group pairing with throughput timer , but the transactions were low , Is there any other way to achieve the above scenario

@dmitri

I happened to use this function ${__tstFeedback(throughput-timer,25,2500,100)} in my concurrent thread group still I what could see is not more than 200 transaction/sec

[Concurency thread group setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v6Mx.png)

[Throughput shaping timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Tmf.png)

[Transactions per sec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw6xX.png)

I always see this additional request added to my summary and aggregate reports results Concurrency Thread Group-ThreadStarter:

Concurrency Thread Group-ThreadStarter: 15034   27152   314 67905   17924.575009281336  0.5485566050286018  27.972210128343956  101.83185588876516  3.662355576998932   3727.836304376746

Answer (score 0):

It **might be** a valid scenario depending on your application response time.

In order to be able to achieve 500 requests/second with 25 users each user needs to be able to execute 20 requests per second which means that your application response time needs to be 50 milliseconds or less.

If response time is above 50 milliseconds the number of requests per second will reduce proportionally.

If you have more than 1 request in your transaction - the response time constraint changes correspondingly like 2 requests - 25 milliseconds max, etc.

JMeter's [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) can only capable of **pausing** the threads to limit the number of transactions per minute to the given value, if the current amount is not enough - it won't kick off extra threads. So it's your job to provide sufficient number of threads in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

As the alternative you can consider going for [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination, they can be connected via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so if current number of threads is not enough to reach/maintain the desired throughput - more threads will be launched

Comment: I see the all the api response time to be above 1000 ms and max response time is around 5000ms for one request In this case what should be my schedule feedback function ? , how much virtual users should I set up to achieve 500 transactions/second

Comment: I Would like to also add one more question how can I run another load for all the API's  in parallel  , I have around 20 requests where i need to run same load as above, the only difference is how can i run all the API'S request parallelly

Comment: If your response time can be as high as 5000 milliseconds you will need minimum 2500 virtual users (it's kind of high number so make sure to follow recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article. . With regards to your second question, it's better to start a new thread,  normally  different groups of business users are represented by different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

Comment: Thanks for sharing Dmitri !! I have made changes to existing script and tried what i see is not more than 200 transaction can you please take a look I have added edits to my original question

Comment: Your images are very beautiful

Comment: why is 500 TPS is not being achieved here ? Any idea ?

Comment: Either JMeter is not capable of producing the required load or your application cannot handle it, monitor resources usage on both sides using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/). Also take a look at [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime) and [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime) charts as I don't think your feedback function configuration is very appropriate. You should also add some ramp-up and increase test duration

Comment: have you noticed this before ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66492218/why-is-my-start-and-end-time-in-apache-jmeter-dashboard-report-showing-1-min-dif

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66530533/why-is-there-additional-label-sample-getting-added-to-the-aggregate-and-summar