# Why is my start and end time in apache jmeter dashboard report showing 1 min difference when the test actually had run for 10minutes?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

Tried running my test via command prompt in non gui mode the test had run for 10 min and html report got generated but the start and end time shows it had just run for a minute

[Command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCyHt.png)

[JMeter dashboard report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn8Bf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest JMeter 5.4.1

[image]

So I can think of 2 possibilities:

1. You're sitting on an old version of JMeter which is suffering from a some form of a [bug](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) which is fixed in a later release. In this case you need to upgrade, moreover according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you're supposed to be using the latest stable version, it can be obtained from [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page
2. You're generating the dashboard from the wrong [.jtl file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles)

It might also be the case you're opening the wrong folder in the browser but I don't want even to think about this.

Comment: The version I am currently using is 5.2.1 , as you suggested will try updating  next version Btw 2nd possibility that can't be since i am generating both at the same time jtl and dashboard via command prompt

Comment: Have you noticed this in any of the report you have worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66530533/why-is-there-additional-label-sample-getting-added-to-the-aggregate-and-summar